# Translate X or left tends to affect the height of absolutely postioned div

Tags: html, css, position

I have faced a weird CSS quirk where i am trying to have a full screen Nav for mobile, which works fine until there is some translateX or left:something, on any sibling div/element, the absolutely positioned div heights does not take the full screen especially in mobile devices, here is the code someone can try to see the issue

Note:- do not run the code snippet below as it fails to reproduce the error i am facing, copy and paste the below code in your local machine and then open the responsive window and try to select the phone devices

```css
*,
::after,
::before{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


nav{
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

nav>ul>li{
    list-style: none;
}

#mobile-nav{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    opacity:0.5;
}

section{
    transform: translateX(50%);
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mobile-nav"></div>
    <nav class="nav">
     <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        <li>Carrers</li>
        <li>Support</li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <section></section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. your code works. Remember, position: abolute remove items from normal flow...

Comment: try to run the code locally in your ide! you will see the div wont cover the whole screen in mobile devices.

Comment: I'll suggest you to read more about position:absolute.